# Russian space observatory Spektr-UV

Tags: spacecraft, imaging, space-telescope

Where can I find more detailed information about [Spectr-UV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spektr-UV)? I'm interested to find an in-depth article and/or images of it's components. It seems that it could have offered a unique capability, why haven't there been more space-based UV observatories?

[image]

**above:** drawing of Spektr-UV from [russianspaceweb.org](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/spektr_uf.html).

Comment: More detail than what?

Comment: http://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask perhaps start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spektr-UV

Comment: There have been UV space telescopes before. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_astronomy

Comment: I've added the image based from a link in the list provided in [this helpful answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/19005/12102).

Answer (score 3):

You can find some information on Spectr-UV by searching the web.  I've included three links to the Spektr-UV/Spectr-UF mission below. The third gives details of the three planned spectrometers.

There have been more than a dozen space based dedicated UV telescopes/instruments plus two on Hubble (see the link to the Wikipedia List of Space Telescopes article).  During the most recent Hubble Servicing Mission in 2009, STIS (the Space Telescope Imaging Spectrograph) was repaired and COSTAR was replaced with COS (the Cosmic Origins Spectrograph).  Both of these are UV instruments.  The planned follow on to Hubble, LUVOIR (the Large UltraViolet, Optical, InfraRed survey telescope) will have at least one multi-purpose ultraviolet instrument.

Spectr-UV links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spektr-UV

http://www.russianspaceweb.com/spektr_uf.html

http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/spektr-uf.htm

List of space telescopes (in the Contents list, click on Ultraviolet): 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_telescopes

STIS (on the HST) links:

https://www.spacetelescope.org/about/general/instruments/stis/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Telescope_Imaging_Spectrograph

COS (on the HST) links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Origins_Spectrograph

http://www.stsci.edu/hst/cos

https://www.spacetelescope.org/about/general/instruments/cos/